# Advanced custom fields for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Advanced custom fields for wordpress... Plugin

source: http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/discussion/2784/image-fields-on-custom-post-type-values-have-all-gone

I updated my advanced custom fields and all image field values have disapeared.

I checked in the database and i still see the information but they're not linking up correct.

God.. any ideas? :(

Comment: Can you share some code please?

Comment: Go to the ACF fields page and click update database.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better check out the depreciated bits of code. I found this same issue with the_repeater_field (http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/functions/the_repeater_field/) it got depreciated and I had to update my code to the right functions.

Check this page out to see if any of these relate to your problem: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/functions/

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Bonzer Custom Fields Creator: 
**https://wordpress.org/plugins/bonzer-custom-fields/**

It creates wide array of input fields at various places inside the wordpress admin panel.
Places in the wordpress admin panel where custom fields are applicable includes:

- All Post Types
- All Taxonomies
- Pages:

  - Dashboard (Home)
  - Users (Your Profile)
  - Settings (All Pages)

Give it a try, I am sure you will love it.